# Conditional always evaluates as if true

Tags: php, jquery

I wrote this post function in my jquery plugin and then faced to a strange problem .

Is the condition statement in this jquery code correct ?

```
if(info = "enabled"){
    $("#mod"+mod_id+" > img.status").attr("src","images/active.gif");
}else if(info = "disabled"){
    $("#mod"+mod_id+" > img.status").attr("src","images/inactive.gif");
}else{
    $("#waiting"+mod_id).delay(2000).html(\'<img src="images/error.png" />\'+data);
}
```

Problem is that it only returns the value enabled and can't handle the "disabled" value

Comment: Get those single `=` in your if-statements to be the comparison operator `==`. You're using the assignment operator. You only get the one case because the assignment `info = "enabled"` will always be `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is assignment

jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mbbjh/

```
if(info = "enabled"){ //wrong
```

this is comparision

```
if(info == "enabled"){
```

try trim also if you have any spaces coming

```
if($.trim(info).toLowerCase()=="enabled") {
```

Comment: i tested this == but doesn't follow the statement and it returns the value in else() statement . although it says the value is for example "enabled"

Comment: @mac , did you compare the case , are they both same case not like Enabled and enabled??

Comment: yes its the same .. in php file when data is entered in database it  echo "enabled" and if not it will be "disabled"

Answer (score 1):

you must use `==` (equality) or `===` (Identity) to compare expressions instead of `=`.

I'd recommend using `===` this prevents type conversion and returns true if a value and a type of expressions are both same.

Comment: i should have mentioned that I know the correct version is == but when i use the operator it returns the else() value.

Comment: notes = 'enabled' always converts to true so you won't get to any of the else statements. when you use a correct syntax, check if the value of notes is really equal to the value you're comparing it.(alert(notes))

Comment: I'm confused , it returns not equal ...  it can't be right ..  enabled should be equal to "enabled"

Comment: try using jQuery.trim(notes)=='enabled' maybe a space char has crept in the string.

Answer (score 0):

==, not =

simple as that..........